# Why does my vuex state change on changing my component level state even if I have not binded the vuex state to any html input element?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-devtools

I have a vue store which has the following

> *store.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const state = {
      supplementStore: {}
    }

const actions = {
  getDataFromApi ({dispatch, commit}) {
    APIrunning.then(response => {
      commit('SET_SUPPLEMENT', response)
    })
  }
}

const mutations = {
  SET_SUPPLEMENT (state, data) {
    state.supplementStore= data
  }
}

const foodstore = {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  mutations
}

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    foodstore
  }
})
```

My vue component looks like this

> *Supp.vue*

```
<template>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="supps.logged">
</template>

<script>
import {mapState, mapActions} from 'vuex'
import store from './store'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      supps: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.supps = this.supplementStore
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('foodstore', ['supplementStore'])
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see I have a component level state called `supps` which is assigned the value of `supplementStore` (which is a vuex state) as soon as it is `mounted`.

```
mounted () {
  this.supps = this.supplementStore
},
```

`supplementStore` gets its value from the the API and it is a JSON object which looks like this

```
supplementStore = {
  logged: true
}
```

Therefore, when my `Supp.vue` component is mounted my local state `supps` will become

```
supps = {
    logged: true
  }
```

`supps` is binded to an input field of type checkbox `(Supp.vue)` using the `v-model` directive.

> What I want to achieve:

When I toggle the checkbox, `supps.logged` should toggle between `true` and `false` but, `supplementStore.logged` should remain unchanged (since I have not binded it to my input field).

> What I observe in my `Vue Devtools`:

When I toggle the checkbox, both `supps.logged` AND `supplementStore.logged` are toggling in sync i.e both of them are toggling in sync between true and false, whereas I want only `supps.logged` to get toggled.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data I was receiving from the API into `supplementStore` was in the form of an array of objects:

```
supplementStore =  [
    {
        "logged": true
    },
    {
        "logged": false
    }
]
```

And as Jacob Goh and Yousof K. mentioned in their respective answers that objects and arrays get passed by reference in javascript, I decided to use the following code to assign the value of `supplementStore` to `supps` inside my `mounted()` hook:

```
mounted () {
    let arr = []
      for (let i = 0; i < this.supplementStore.length; i++) {
        let obj = Object.assign({}, this.supplementStore[i])
        arr.push(obj)
      }
      this.supps = arr

  }
```

Now when I toggle my checkbox, `supplementStore.logged` remains unchanged while `supps.logged` toggles between true and false just the way I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, object is passed by reference. (This is a reasonably good explanation => https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c)

To avoid this problem, you can clone the object when assigning to `supps`.

```
mounted () {
  this.supps = { ...this.supplementStore } // cloning the object using Javascript Spread syntax
},
```

Comment: the solution you provided does not seems to work. `supplementStore  ` still changes

Comment: I do, but the actual code belongs to my employer, hence can't share it here. I think the problem is that `supplementStore ` in my actual code is an array of objects `[
    {
        "logged": true
    },
    {
        "logged": false
    }
]` and I'm looping the input checkbox field inside a v-for directive

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Object.assign` instead? In JS objects are passed by reference. Assigning one to a variable will cause the original one to change if the variable is changed inside.

To clone an object, you may try this:

```
// this.assignedObj = new object. 
// this.obj = original object.
this.assignedObj = Object.assign({}, this.obj);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mr7x4yn0/

Edit: As you can see from the demo, `Vue.set` or `this.$set` will not work for you (probably).